# How to get output by using multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to get a personalised message for each name corresponding to a mail defined by a list(a know how to get around this problem by using dictionary but dont know about lists).Can anyone help me by telling me how its done?

```
mail_id=['asd@g','nsg@g','psg@g']
names_list=['asd','nsg','psg']

for names in names_list:
    for mail in mail_id:
        msg='{}\n{}'.format(names,mail)
        print(msg)
```

the output which this gives is:

```
asd
asd@g
asd
nsg@g
asd
psg@g
nsg
asd@g
nsg
nsg@g
nsg
psg@g
psg
asd@g
psg
nsg@g
psg
psg@g
```

The desired output:

```
 asd
 asd@g
 nsg
 nsg@g
 psg
 psg@g
```

here once again we can use indices to get the desired output but it'll be long and tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` here.

```
for name,mail in zip(names_list,mail_id):
    print(f'{name}\n{mail}')
```

---

```
asd
asd@g
nsg
nsg@g
psg
psg@g
```

Comment: @JosephChotard `zip` returns a zip object which is an iterator, it doesn't create new tuple. Even the return type of `enumerate` is enumerate object which in an iterator. And when `next` function used on both zip and enumerate returns a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip and enumerate to get the output.

```
for i, j in enumerate (zip(mail_id,names_list)):
    print (j[1])
    print (j[0])

asd
asd@g
nsg
nsg@g
psg
psg@g
```

Answer (score 2):

If they're guaranteed to be in the same order you can just use the following:

```py
mail_id=['asd@g','nsg@g','psg@g']
names_list=['asd','nsg','psg']
for index, name in enumerate(names_list):
   print(name)
   print(mail_id[index])
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

if you like one line solution you could use a generator expression:

```
print(*('\n'.join(t) for t in zip(names_list, mail_id)), sep='\n')
```

output:

```
asd
asd@g
nsg
nsg@g
psg
psg@g
```